# rolify, simple_form and multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, user-interface, simple-form, rolify

i have following data structure:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  resourcify
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  resourcify
end
```

and of course models User and Role :) As you understand - i'd like to  manage access to organisations and projects using rolify gem. I'd like to create controller to add and remove roles from user and i prefer simple_form gem in the views. Of course - i can create two different pages - one for management roles for organizations and one - for projects, but i think it's not so usable. I'd like to have just one page with ability to manage roles for some user with ability to change what he can manage.

As an example - on the page i'd like to choose role :org_admin and i'll have no additional parameters to choose or i can choose roles :project_manager or :developer and i'll be able to choose project for those roles.

Do you have any ideas how to do it with best practices? Maybe any example?

Comment: Your question is pretty broad and hard to answer, read the rolify documentation: https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify and then read simple_form's documentation:  https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Then come back with more code implementing your idea when/if you get stuck.

Comment: @Kelseydh, thanks for your comment, but you gave no answer and no any idea how to implement what i need. I use rolify and simple form for some years and there are no problem to implement roles in app or any complex form. I'm looking for best practices. Of course i can check what kind of role is requested and display one more input for target, but i'm not sure that it is good enough.